# PLSQL Getting values from string

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this varchar2(2000) string:

```
id=100\nid2=0\nid3=0\dtext='more Text'
```

and I want to get only the values e.g. `more Text` or `0` (id3).

I was trying to use a customized SPLIT function, where separator is \n but this only returns me for example `id3=0` (in this case I need '0' as result).

How can I do this more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get all the values with something like this:

```
WITH DATA AS
  (SELECT q'[id=100\nid2=0\nid3=0\ndtext='more Text']' str FROM dual)      
SELECT replace(substr(regexp_substr(str,'(=.+?\n)|(=.+?$)',1,level),2),'\n') v    
FROM DATA
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(regexp_replace(str,'([^=]+=.+?\n)|([^=]=.+?$)'))
```

Comment: Wow, thats amazing. I need to have a look for those RegEx. How to get rid of the quotes e.g. `'more Text'`

Answer (score 2):

> and I want to get only the values e.g. more Text.

Simply use **SUBSTR** and **INSTR**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT q'[id=100\nid2=0\nid3=0\dtext='more Text']' str FROM dual
  3    )
  4  SELECT SUBSTR(str,instr(str, '''')+1,LENGTH(SUBSTR(str,instr(str, '''')))-2) str
  5  FROM DATA
  6  /

STR
---------
more Text

SQL>
```

Comment: Your solution means, I have to count for each occurence to get the right content, right?

Comment: But how to get the content for id3 for example?

Comment: In my solution, I considered the text between the single quotes.

Comment: Do you mean you need all the values immediately after `=` sign?